# MonkeyRunner send "Action/Next" key

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

Using MonkeyRunner how can I send the "next/action" key? It's the one on the bottom right corner of the android keyboard. Most of the time it's the same action as "KEYCODE_ENTER" or "KEYCODE_TAB" but not always.

I tried

- device.press('ACTION_DOWN', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
- device.press('ACTION_UP', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
- device.press('FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)

but it's not one of those.

Answer (score 0):

from the android developers webpage what you have mentioned is `FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION`.
see [keyevents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION/)

Comment: As I said, this doesn't work:
device.press('FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)

Comment: so I guess it's impossible...?

Comment: in what scenario you want to use this key ? i mean any other equivalent key for your purpose ?

Comment: For example when you log into an account, you type your login and then to go to the next field (usualy the password field) you can press this "Action Key". I know what you are going to say : press "TAB" or "Enter" but on some applications they don't have the same effect as the "Action Key".